# Visual Studio 2010 "Press any key to continue . . ." does not show

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

"Press any key to continue" wordings do not show in console when my app finishes execution.

I know this prompt should be showing in "start without debugging" mode, but it does not! As soon as I enter any parameter and hit enter, console window closes without showing the output...

What should I do to make the console app prompt me for any key when it finishes execution?

Comment: Did you run it with F5 or CTRL-F5?

Comment: Launch the application with Ctrl+F5

Comment: Seems like a valid question to me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to [comments about a VS2010 bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/540969/missing-press-any-key-to-continue-when-lauching-with-ctrl-f5), you should get desired behavior if you set the subsystem property of the project to "console". Go to menu Project > Properties > in new window select Configuration Properties > Linker > System > property SubSystem should have the value **Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)**

Comment: I did not find Linker under Configuration Properties. But you gave me an idea. I created a new project choosing Console application template and that worked! I usually create empty projects, that must have caused the issue.

Comment: Linker section should be between C/C++ and Manifest Tool sections (at least it is in VS2008). If this answer is your accepted answer then you should mark it as such (click on hollow check mark on the left side).

Comment: I am using Express edition, maybe it is different. Anyways, thanks!
EDIT: Found it! Thanks!

Comment: Worked for VS 2013 as well, same location.  If you had trouble seeing it under `System` (it was greyed out for me), you can also look under `All Options`.

Comment: Answers the question.  This problem occurred for me when switching from VS 2012 to VS 2017.

Answer (score -1):

In your `main` method, add a `Try...Catch...Finally` block as shown:

This will ensure that any exceptions you are getting will be displayed, and that the user will have to take action to close the command window.

```
try 
{
    // Your existing code
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // Log the exception, e.g:
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
finally
{
    Console.WriteLine ("Please press any key to close");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: The question is on C++, but the answer is in C#

Comment: The question was not marked as C++ when I answered it - see http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9175627/revisions and note that I was viewing revision 1.